# infopath 2010 not able to filter

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have an SharePoint list in which I am using the Infopath form and over there I have a column called **business lead**. and I have more than one **business lead** for the project. 
The issue I am facing is I am unable to filter that column. I get a message "

> "Cannot show the value of the filter. The field may not be filterable
>   or the number of items returned exceeds the list view threshold
>   enforced by administrator"

Is it because I am using InfoPath?

Since on other list or libraries I am able to do only on this I am unable to do.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed. On the List settings. open that column and Under "Allow selection of" Select people only. Once that is done it worked. But later when i selected People and Groups also it started working. Not sure the reason. But happy that it started working. The filter starts working. let me know if that helps.

Thanks
Mohammed